# PL-SQL explicit cursors

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a PL?SQL statement for oracle that selects all unique Industries from a table (Jobs Table) and inserts it into another table called `dim_industry`

```
DECLARE
cursor industries is select unique industry from job;
ind varchar2(20);

BEGIN
  open industries;
  for counter in 1..industries%ROWCOUNT
  LOOP
    FETCH industries into ind;
    insert into dim_industry (IndustryName) values(ind);
  END LOOP;
  close industries;
END;
/
```

The

```
select unique industry from job
```

Selects 10 rows, but when I run the pl-sql, it says 1 row inserted. Also, when I do a

```
select * from dim_industry
```

query, the table remains empty. Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: dude if u do this same case  with collections and bulk collect it's much more efficient yar

Comment: Doing it as a simple SQL "insert into ... select ..." statement would be the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENDLOOP` should be written as `END LOOP`
**UPDATE**
To achieve what you want, You can proceed like this:

```
    DECLARE
    cursor industries is select unique industry from job;
    ind varchar2(20);

    BEGIN
      open industries;
      LOOP
        FETCH industries into ind;
        exit when industries %notfound;
        insert into dim_industry (IndustryName) values(ind);
      END LOOP;
      close industries;
      commit;
    END;
/
```

Comment: thank you. The pl-sql now runs. however, it isnt giving me the result i expected. i am modifying the question, and would be grateful if you would look at it again.

Comment: thank you, this works perfectly. Just to confirm, in this line: exit when industries %notfound;
the %notfound attribute has false when you reach the end of the rows returned right?

Comment: @DavidAldridge: I know that there are much better and faster way of achieving what OP wants..But if you have time then re-read the OP Question again, He/She is not asking for `how to achieve the result fastly` instead he/she is asking to fix the error that he/she is getting in PL/SQL code. Try to be flexible in thought process..Just down voting someone on behalf of own perception doesn't reflect your maturity and intelligence.

Comment: @VishalK If someone asks "How do I knock in a nail with a screwdriver", and gets a response, "Turn it round and hit the nail with the handle", then I'll downvote that as well. It's in my fundamental nature.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Don't relate it with nails and screwdriver , that doesn't prove anything.. If you feel that you are so correct in your decision then Can you tell me what was the perpose of OP to put this question here.?

Comment: @VishalK it's common for developers to believe that cursor based methods are faster than SQL, or not to consider it at all. That is especially true of non-DBMS developers writing PL/SQL. I think we do developers a greater service by educating them in this issue than in fixing bugs, especially if the bug arises from using an incorrect approach.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: I totally agree with your words. But it doesn't mean that if someone wants to learn `cursor` behaviour in PL/SQL then he/she can't give it a try. Although not very effective but OP is still in the process of learning..

Comment: @DavidAldridge i am new to developing, and did not realise that you could use a select after an insert to insert multiple rows. You should try to offer constructive critisism instead of downvoting the answers of others who are just trying to help.

Comment: @VishalK I'm find with learning exercises as long as it's clear that that's what they are, but I'm teaching correct methodology as well as correct syntax -- if all we were interested in was correcting syntax then 99% of answers would be a link to the documentation that the questioner couldn't be bothered to consult.

Comment: @ErnestTambie It's lovely for people to try and help, but Stackoverflow is about getting software development right. There are right methods and wrong methods and some shades of grey in between, and the clearly wrong is always going to get a downvote. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

All the previous answers are improvements - and BULK COLLECTION is a very useful tool. But you generally don't need to use PL/SQL to copy data around. In your case, try just using an INSERT ... SELECT statement like so :-

```
INSERT INTO dim_industry( IndustryName )
SELECT DISTINCT industry
FROM job
```

PL/SQL is a last resort IMHO. I've even implemented constraint solving in straight Oracle SQL!

Comment: thank you, i did not realise you could insert multiple rows via a select statement

Answer (score 1):

skip that step:

```
DECLARE 
    TYPE T_IND IS TABLE of job.industry%TYPE;
    ind T_IND;
BEGIN
    SELECT UNIQUE industry BULK COLLECT INTO ind FROM job;
    FORALL i IN ind.FIRST..ind.LAST
        INSERT INTO dim_industry (IndustryName) VALUES (ind(i));
    -- don't forget to commit;
END;
/
```

Comment: you're welcome! yes, this works and is much faster in terms of performances.

Comment: As usual I tried to match the original arquitecture of the OP yet providing pedagogic improvements. But I guess you're right.

Answer (score -1):

hey i think your doing in other route which is quite lengthy!!!just try this dude

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1
  iS
    select unique industry from job;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c1
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO dim_industry (IndustryName) VALUES
      (i.industry
      );
  END LOOP;
  commit;
END;
/
```

if you use `for loop` for cursor then no need mention `open  and close` it has implicitly open and close.
note:if you want to update or insert of delete operation on table using cursor better user collections with bulk operation it's much faster than this.

**this is second way to do the same;**

```
DECLARE
temp HR.departments.department_name%type;
  CURSOR c1
  iS
    SELECT DISTINCT d.department_name FROM hr.departments d;
BEGIN
  open c1;
  LOOP
  fetch c1  into temp;
    INSERT INTO thiyagu.temp_dep VALUES
      (temp
      );
      dbms_output.put_line(temp);
      exit when c1%notfound;
  END LOOP;
  close c1;
  commit;
END;
/
```

***this is third and efficient way;***

```
DECLARE

type test_type is  table of job.industry%type;

col test_type;

BEGIN
  select unique industry bulk collect into col from job;
  forall i in col.first..col.last insert into dim_industry values(col(i));
  dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);
  commit;

END;
/
```

Comment: If you recommend BULK COLLECT / FORALL, you should also mention the LIMIT clause and how to use it. Performing a bulk collect might easily blow up your process memory if your select returns a large number of rows.

Comment: @ Frank Schmitt:ya obviously but in this case we are handling only 10 records!but i should put!k k dude

Comment: @ David Aldridge:ya we can use simply by using SQL but the thing is i try to figure out possible ways!for huge data!

Comment: It's faster to just use SQL for huge data, small data, or no data at all. There's no situation I know of where a cursor based method will be faster than SQL, and it will always require more code, which implies more bugs and more difficult maintenance.